# Trying to prove that $\int f'(x)dx=f(x)$ gone wrong

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives, fake-proofs

I was trying to prove that $$\int f'(x)dx=f(x)+C$$($f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x)$ is integrable) when I got this instead: $\int f'(x)dx=\int \frac{f(x)}{x}dx-f(0)\ln|x|+C.$
Here is how I got this: $$\int f'(x)dx=\int \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}dx=\int\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{x-h}dx-\int\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(h)}{x-h}dx=\int\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-\int\frac{f(0)}{x}dx=\int\frac{f(x)}{x}dx-f(0)\ln|x|.$$

I think I got this wrong when I split the limit, but it is convergent anyways. So where did I do this incorrectly?

Comment: $f'(x)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}$ is already wrong.

Comment: Why not solve like this,  let $$f(x) = t $$   $$ f^'(x)\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}t$$   Then we get, $$ \int f^'(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int \mathrm{d}t = t + c $$   hence   $$ \int f^'(x) \mathrm{d}x  = f(x) + c $$

Comment: @LuckyChouhan you presumably see that your math display is all kookie... My suggestion (which I even sometimes think to heed) is to test and correct complicated 'comments' in the answer section (which probably should be there anyway) before copying and pasting them as a comment.  Otherwise I inevitably mess up...

Comment: @peterag yeah, I noticed, but I typed latex with that double dollar sign, it is still happening. how to correct it? I tried by giving double space but didn't work.

Comment: To the well intentioned downvoter, what was the reason for doing this? My problem is clear. If the mistake is obvious then it is to you and not me.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. It's a well written question that shows work. The fact that you may have an elementary misunderstanding (that you're trying to correct, I might add) doesn't warrant a downvote. It's best not to think too much about the reason's why people downvote. Have a +1 for trying to improve your math.

Comment: @C-RAM Thanks for your comment and upvote! There are people that keep downvoting my posts lately, and I am not sure why.

Comment: Maybe some people think you're asking something obvious? Nobody knows except the downvoter(s), but I don't think your posts deserve a downvote, especially after reading your bio and your most recent questions. I wouldn't worry about seeing some negative numbers on a computer screen. Sometimes, I get downvotes too even after structuring my questions exactly according to MSE's guidelines.

Comment: @Accelerator Thanks for your comment! But the thing is, even if I asked something obvious (which isn't since the mistake was small and hard to spot) then they must be patient with me. I think there are people just trolling around in Stack Exchange. Also, someone downvoted one of my posts (the one linked in the OP) a few minutes ago!

Comment: There's a script that detects anomalous voting patterns and runs periodically. If it detects a problem, the votes will be reversed. If the downvotes remain otherwise, flag one for moderator attention and explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we do not know anything about $f$ (continuity etc...). Second, the derivative is defined as
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow x } \frac{f(x)-f(h)}{x-h}
$$
and not the way you defined it.

Also, rather try to prove $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int^t_a f(s)~\mathrm{d}s = f(t)$ for continuous $f$.

Comment: Well if $f'$ exists then we **do** know that $f$ is differentiable (and consequently also continuous)

Comment: Well duh, but we still do not know whether $f'$ is even integrable.

Comment: I edited my OP, so the function is differentiable and its derivative is integrable.

Comment: Thank you, much better now...